# oracle 11g xe user data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I'm running Oracle 11g XE on Debian Linux and I really need to know when "user data" is come close to 11 Gb.

> The maximum amount of user data in an Oracle Database XE database cannot exceed 11 gigabytes. If the user data grows beyond this limit, then an ORA-12592 error will appear.

(c) [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW118)

Few questions here:

1. what is user data exactly?
2. Which tablespaces is count as `userdata`?
3. Does system tablespaces like `sysaux` counts as user data?
4. Does separate files like archived redo logs `counts` as `userdata`?

Thank for help, guys, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 2):

User data is the persistent data your application creates and uses, as distinct from the metadata the database generates itself (such as the data dictionary).

The tablespaces you need to monitor are USERS and any other tablespace you have created. The tablespaces SYS and SYSAUX are reserved for the database's own data and so don't count; TEMP and UNDO (or whatever else you call your temporary and rollback tablespaces) don't count either.

Redo logs and other files are external to the database and so don't count either.

Comment: Thats just what ive been looking for. Thanks for help.